# Extracting files from deep within a zip file in python

Tags: python, zip, unzip

I am working on a script that can automate data extraction from a zip file that we get from the Sentinel 2B satellite.

The files I need from the zip file have a path something like this:
`zipfile.zip/somefolder.SAFE/GRANULE/main_folder/IMG_DATA/`

They are all .jp2 files, and I need to extract them to another path with the following structure:
`my_path/main_folder/`

I need to retain this main_folder name (it varies from file to file) from the zip file.

Ziplist is a list of zip file paths

```
for i in zipList:
    if not os.path.exists(basePath + '/Raw_data/' + os.path.basename(i)[:-4]):
        os.makedirs(basePath + '/Raw_data/' + os.path.basename(i)[:-4])

    zipped_file = zipfile.ZipFile(i, 'r')
    for file in zipped_file.namelist():
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, "*.jp2"):
            zipped_file.extract(file, basePath + '/Raw_data/' + os.path.basename(i)[:-4])
```

But this maintains the file structure of the zip file.
I want just the .jp2 files in `/Raw_data/os.path.basename(i)[:-4]`

Comment: Please try it yourself first. We're here to help solve problems, not for writing code for others.

Comment: @Justlearnedit I just added my code, please see if you can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
for i in zipList:
    folder_path = basePath + '/Raw_data/' + os.path.basename(i)[:-4]
    if not os.path.exists(folder_path):
        os.makedirs(folder_path)
    # print(os.path.basename(i))
    z = zipfile.ZipFile(i, 'r')
    for file in z.namelist():
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, "*.jp2") and str(file)[-8:-4] in ["_B02", "_B03", "_B04", "_B08"]:
            target = open(folder_path + '/' + os.path.basename(file), 'wb')
            target.write(z.read(file))
            target.close()
    z.close()
```

I had to create a new file at the location, and copy over the jp2 file from the zip file to it.